# Python MySQLdb "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" even though it has been installed

Tags: python, build, mysql-python

I'm attempting to connect to a MySql database and use its data for some code, though when I'm using

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

it gives me an error stating:

> "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

This link provided does not work, though i found out the correct link and installed the build tools as well as the "Windows 10 SDK" as other posts have specified.
I sadly still am getting this error.

Anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: "pip install mysqlclient

NOTE: Wheels for Windows may be not released with source package. You should pin version in your requirements.txt to avoid trying to install newest source package." https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you need MySQL database, this is installed by other means i.e. see Microsoft webpage for details (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html).

If you just want to connect to MySQL database from Python, try installing mysql-connector instead.

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Comment: Installing mysql-connector was not enough for my project using Django.

Answer (score 1):

It's a complicated environment.

I suggest to use pyodbc to connect to your database ( it isn't required by c++ compiler installation)

Try to convert the below code in your program

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SOCKET=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;UID=rooter;PWD=sshh')
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation too? I'd prefer to use the normal mysqlclient

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1- Download mysqlclient wheel on [Unoffical Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages.](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (search for mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win32)

2- Install manually `pip install mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`